# No 'visited' entry in User Profile in SE Metas

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page, visited-days

There is no `visited` entry in the User Profile page in the new Metas for SE.  Could we please add this in?  I know it's possible to get the Enthusiast badge in the Metas, so it would be good to have that info.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This ones an old-y, but should be completed after our next build.

Answer (score 0):

I can see it just fine (using Ubuntu Meta as example):

[image]

Comment: Posted mine off of Meta SuperUser, and checked the other four Metas I'm on, all the same.

Comment: That's because you're a moderator. I can see it on Web Applications, but not on any of the others - including meta.SU and meta.SF

Comment: I see it on Unix (where I'm a mod), but nowhere else. Is it a mod-only thing on the SE metas? EDIT: Ah, ChrisF beat me to it; that appears to be it